# React добавить дочерней компоненте onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-events, jsx

У меня есть множество компоентов в dropdown списке. Надо чтобы при нажатии на любой из элементов списка, происходило конкретное действие.

Если я делаю так:

```
functiion filter() {
    return(
        <div className={`${styles.option_list} no_decorate`}>
            {Object.entries(selectedItem).map(region => {
                let test = 'test'
                return <Card key={uniqueKeyGenerator()} region={region[0]} selected={region[1]} onClick={(test) => console.log(test)} />
            }
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

function Card({ region, selected = false }) {
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.option} ${selected ? styles.selected : ''}`}>
            {region}
        </div>
    )
}
```

то в консоли не выводится ничего. Если же я делаю так:

```
functiion filter() {
    return(
        <div className={`${styles.option_list} no_decorate`}>
            {Object.entries(selectedItem).map(region => {
                let test = 'test'
                return <Card key={uniqueKeyGenerator()} region={region[0]} selected={region[1]} onClick={(test) => console.log(test)} />
            }
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

function Card({ region, selected = false, onClick }){
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick} className={`${styles.option} ${selected ? styles.selected : ''}`}>
            {region}
        </div>
    )
}
```

то в консоли выводится это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос** - как мне реализовать реакцию на событие `onClick` с передачей параметра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
  const onClickHandler = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  return <Card onClickHandler={onClickHandler} />;
}


export default function Card({ onClickHandler }) {
  return <button onClick={() => onClickHandler("test")}>Click me</button>;
}
```

[Пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-bush-blj1e?file=/src/Card.js)

Comment: Да, это сработало, спасибо. Но мне на будущее, была ли возможность сделать то же самое, но передачу параметра в onClickHandler произвести при инициализации компонента Card?

Comment: Как правило всегда все методы которые влияют на отображение выносят в родительский компонент. А в дочерние передают уже ссылки на этот метод. Если надо передать значение, а с ним работать в дочернем компоненте, то просто передавайте его через пропс и используйте уже в методах дочернего компоненат.